# Is there a definitive curses menu library (menu.h) reference?

Tags: c, curses

I am using curses to create a menu in C.

I have been using the following resources: [ncurses man pages](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html) and the [tldp how-to](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/menus.html#MENUWINDOWS).

While the former provides a great reference for curses.h functions, and the latter has a nice introductory section on the menu library, I am unable to find a good reference for it. I have examined my local copy of menu.h, but it doesn't help me determine what each function actually does.

Is there any official reference for this "ncurses menu library"?

Comment: [This](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/menu.3x.html)? Its also in the source download at `ncurses-5.9/doc/html/man/menu.3x.html`.

Comment: The ncurses manpages are very complete. There's a little O'Reilly book that used to be quite good, but from what I can gather, it's now badly out-of-date.

Comment: @user2802841 Yes! That is exactly what I was looking for. It was so close to what I was looking at too. Please make it an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Emmet Yes, the manpages are great! As the above commenter pointed out, the information I was looking for was right in front of me.

Comment: @Gary No worries, everyone sometimes overlooks something :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the reference is:

- [online here](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/menu.3x.html),
- located at `doc/html/man/menu.3x.html` in the source download,
- `man menu` should work as well if you have ncurses man pages installed (`sudo apt-get install ncurses-doc` on Debian/Ubuntu).